# How to test AEM(CQ5) Dispatcher

Tags: aem

I am trying to set up CQ5 Dispatcher for the first time.  I have gone through the documentation up to a point where it says "You may wish to test the newly installed Dispatcher against a working AEM publish instance, to ensure that a baseline correct install has been acheived."

How do I do this?  I am clueless.

I'm using Microsoft IIS 7.5 as my web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test it simply by trying to access your publisher instance through the dispatcher:

```
http://addressofyourdispatcher/content/geometrixx/en.html
```

If you get content, it is working.